# EF6: Possibility to use Navigation Property value outside of the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use a `using` block to select a dataset from the database with Entity Framework:

```
protected StagingProcessingEngineStatus GetProcessingStatusEntryById (Guid processingId) {
    using (var context = new ProcessingEntities()) {
        var matchedPlan = context.StagingProcessingEngineStatus.FirstOrDefault(plan => plan.ProcessingId == processingId && plan.Owner == this.UserCredentials.UserId.ToString());        

        return matchedPlan;
    }
}
```

The `StagingProcessingEngineStatus` entity contains a navigation property to another entity called `StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary`:

```
public partial class ProcessingEntities : DbContext {
    public virtual DbSet<StagingProcessingEngineStatus> StagingProcessingEngineStatus { get; set; }
}    


public partial class StagingProcessingEngineStatus {
    public virtual StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary { get; set; }
}
```

Now I try to use the return value of the `GetProcessingStatusEntryById` method to access the content of the `StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary` property of `StagingProcessingEngineStatus`.

But the gives me the following exception:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and cannot be used for
>   operations anymore, which require a connection.

Is there a possibility to access the value of the navigation property outside of the `using` block like below?

```
var stagingPlan = this.GetProcessingStatusEntryById(processingId);

var library = GetProcessingLibraryByXmlString(stagingPlan.StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary.LibraryXml);
```

Comment: Either do not dispose the context (remove the `using`) to keep lazy loading functional, or use eager loading (`.Include(e => e.StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary)`)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks! That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Either do not dispose the context (remove the `using`) to keep lazy loading functional, or use eager loading (`.Include(e => e.StagingRefProcessingEngineLibrary`)